# How do I let pip install into HOME by default?

Tags: python, pip

I want that `pip` always installs into `$HOME` just as if I type

```
pip install --user ...
```

But I don't want to type `--user` all the time. I think setting an environment variable would be a good solution but I'm not sure and I didn't find anything.

Comment: @Keyser `$PYTHONUSERBASE` defines the place where things get installed when I *use (aka type)* `--user`. The goal here is to have `$PYTHONUSERBASE` as a default *without* typing `--user`. A virtualenv is not an option for my purposes.

Comment: True :p Then I've got nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution based on the [idea of *unutbu*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18057682/220652):

`~/bin/ppip` (**p** ersonal **pip**):

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$1" == "install" ] || [ "$1" == "bundle" ]
  then
    pip $1 --user ${@:2}
  else
    pip $@
fi
```

Improvements are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a little script:

**mypip:**

```
#!/bin/sh
pip $@ --user
```

Comment: or may be `pip $@ --user ` so that he can use other commands as well like `pip list`

Comment: @abhishekgarg: Thanks for the improvement.

Comment: This won't work for most of the `pip` commands (like `list`) I guess but thanks for the idea. See my answer for the solution I came up with.

Answer (score 0):

Based on other answers, here's a bash function to add to you `.bash_profile`:

```
function pip {
    if [ "$1" == "install" ] || [ "$1" == "bundle" ]; then
        /usr/local/bin/pip $1 --user ${@:2}
    else
        /usr/local/bin/pip $@
    fi
}
```